# How can I add 1 to x in (x,y) pairs in a Path geometry data, then replace the old data with the new one?

Tags: c#, wpf, path

Thank you for helping me! I have some simple C# codes shown below

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   string data_1 = "M-4.31151201443541,459.82996768458L4.78848798556448,444.929957684579...z";

   //......

   private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      data_2 = Regex.Replace(data_1, "((?=[^, ])\\d+\\.\\d+),", (match) => (double.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value) + 1).ToString()+",");

      Mountain.SetValue(Canvas.ClipProperty,Geometry.Parse(data_2));
   }
}
```

I would like to change the **data_1** (original geometry data from a **path in WPF**), adding 1 to each (x,y) pairs in it, then put it into the **ClipProperty** of a canvas.

Now what i'm really confused is where should I  put **Code 1, 2 and 3**,  how should I define them, and how should I arrange the place of **data_1** and **data_2**(should I replace all **data_2** as **data_1**. If I define **code_2** as `string data_2 ......`, the program will have mistake result. If I put `var`   before **code 2**, it seems that **Mountain.ClipProperty** doesn't get changed.I'm really confused about all these stuff.

What should I do to change the **clipProperty of Mountain**?

Thank you!

The **full data_1** is shown here:[full data_1](https://regex101.com/r/vBYBmb/1/)

P.S. I have a timer-tick in this program, so these codes will be run again and again. If I put it like it originally is, I think every time the **code_2** will have the same result because **data_1** is from **code_1**

Comment: Essentially, you want to move the clip left to right. If you're changing x in a loop, isn't that the same as changing or animating the x of a translatetransform?

Comment: Hi Andy, thank you!Yes I'm making it go to right. I'm not quite familiar with translatetransform, so I checked online for a few information, but still not quite suere about it. Could you make an eample of how should I accomplish my goal by using it?

Comment: As a general hint, instead of manipulating and parsing a geometry string, better directly operate on a PolyLineSegment in a PathFigure of a PathGeometry.

Comment: @Andy. I tried  `Mountain.RenderTransform.Transform.X = x.ToString();`(x is a double number), but the results shows there is a mistake in it. How shoud I change it?

Answer (score 0):

Below is my **xmal** for my **path**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Canvas ......>
        <Canvas ......>
            <Canvas x:Name="Color" Height="234.4" Width="288" Canvas.Top="-48.967" Canvas.Left="-97.6">
               <......>
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas ......>
            <Canvas ......>
                <Path x:Name="mountain" Data="..." ... KeyDown="path_KeyDown"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

The **color** canvas and **mountain** path is my target (the whole **data** of **color** is shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/vBYBmb/2/).

Here are some picture for you. This is the [original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq6Oq.png) picture. I want to use **mountain** to clip the shape of **color** like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qutfO.png). To move the **mountain** I'd like to use a **keyDown**, namely that if I press a key, the **mountain** will move 1 higher from its original place, so as to change the **clip** of **color**.

Below are some codes combined the **keyDown** and yours

```
    private void path_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.KeyStates == Keyboard.GetKeyStates(Key.Up))
        {
        var clipGeom = ((Geometry)this.Resources["mountain"]).Clone();
        var yTransform = new TranslateTransform();
        clipGeom.Transform = yTransform;
        Color.Clip = clipGeom;
        var yAnim = new DoubleAnimation { From = 0, To = 900, Duration= new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(9000)) };
        yTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, yAnim);
        }
    }
```

But after I run this program, the **mountain** never move as I press the key. Besides, I think `{}` after `DoubleAnimation` should also be changed a bit to fit my **keyDown operation**. How should I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: The reason I wrote an animation is because you said you had a "timer tick so these codes would be run again and again" Now you seem to want to move just one pixel.  In your code you have a keydown handler that checks whether the key is up. I would remove that if() since it's never going to be true.

Comment: Hi Andy, in fact I'm trying to use key to control **speed** . If I press key for one time, the path will move at the speed of  1 pixel /ms, and if I press for two times, it moves as 2 pixel / ms. This is accomplised by using a timer_tick. :) If I knwo how to move the path for 1 pixell, I can be able to control its speed.

Comment: You can halve the duration which would double the speed. And you can probably just use the to property so it carries on from where it currently is.